# Getting an error Expected a '>' with my struct vector

Tags: c++

What am I doing wrong? The error is right after the word "vector Shareholder" in my function prototype. Is it a glitch with my IDE? I'm using vstudio 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Shareholder
{
    string name;
    string category;
    int shares;
};
                                
void fillVector(vector<Shareholder>& ClientList, int& numClients);
void printVector(vector<Shareholder> ClientList, int numClients);

int main() 
{
    int numClients = 0;
    vector<Shareholder> ClientList;
    fillVector(ClientList, numClients);
    printVector(ClientList, numClients);

}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/WPb9Mazbj. Just copy-pasted your code. Is it a compiler error, or some IntelliSense error? Please, add a complete error message.

Comment: Error (active) E0439 expected a '>'

Comment: IIRC, "E" errors are mosty IntellSense originated. This tool seems to produce a lot of false-positive errors :|

Comment: Yeah I think its a bug because my program runs fine. I tried closing and opening the program but it won't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Intellisense error by creating an entire new project and copy/paste code